# How to enable source map generation in rails 5

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-5

I am trying to setup a rails 5 application with a source map generation for both javascript (CoffeeScript) and css (scsss) in development. What is the configuration I need?

Comment: I don't know much about Javascript/CSS but source map is usually done for production right?

Comment: Well in this case the config.assets.debug = true is going to serve all of the js and css, which will be very slow. So I would like to have the js combined in development as well. But does it make any difference if I am going to enable it in development or production?

Comment: What is scsss? .

Comment: @Nas Nope, just curious

Comment: @sawa Maybe Sassy Cascading Style SheetS :)

Answer (score 1):

Add

```
//= link application.js.map
//= link application.css.map
```

to `app/assets/config/manifest.js`